# How can i upload file from Android using (asmx) .net WebService

Tags: android, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

i have browse the file on mobile and upload to server

**I have Issue in File Upload its give me File Not Found.**

**.Net File Upload method (Server Side Code)**

```
Public Function UploadFiles(ByVal docs As Byte(), ByVal filename As String, ByVal UserId As Integer, ByVal PartnerId As Integer, ByVal IdeaId As Integer) As String
        'Public Function UploadFiles(ByVal doctitle As String, ByVal docdescription As String, ByVal docs As Byte(), ByVal filename As String, ByVal UserId As Integer, ByVal UserType As String, ByVal IdeaId As Integer, ByVal PartnerId As Integer) As String

        Dim NoOfDocs As Integer

        Dim iCount As Integer
        Dim sConId As String
        Dim sConId1 As String
        Dim sConId2 As String
        Dim txtTitle As eCMSLib.Component.TextBox
        Dim txtDesc As eCMSLib.Component.TextBox
        Dim Upload1 As FileStream
        Dim dirname As String
        Dim strDocTitle As String = ""
        Dim strDocDesc As String = ""
        Dim dirconsultee As String
        Dim createdirconsultee As String
        Dim ServerPath As String
        Dim ServerPath1 As String
        Dim strFilename As String
        Dim strOnlyFilename As String = ""
        Dim objDoc As New Elegant.BusinessLogicLayer.DocumentAndResponse
        Dim objIdea As New Ideas
        Dim createdir As String
        NoOfDocs = GetNumberOfUploadDocs(PartnerId)
        Try
            '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Create consultation directory
            dirname = "Idea" & IdeaId
            createdir = Server.MapPath("uploaddocs")

            Dim dir As DirectoryInfo
            Dim tempdir As String
            tempdir = createdir & "\" & dirname
            dir = New DirectoryInfo(tempdir)

            If dir.Exists = True Then
            Else
                dir.Create()
            End If
            '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            'Create the consultee directory
            dirconsultee = "Consultee" & UserId
            'UserID = Integer.Parse(Session("UID_User"))
            createdirconsultee = Server.MapPath("../uploaddocs/Idea" & IdeaId & "")

            Dim dirconsultee1 As DirectoryInfo
            Dim tempdir1 As String
            tempdir1 = createdirconsultee & "\" & dirconsultee
            dirconsultee1 = New DirectoryInfo(tempdir1)

            If dirconsultee1.Exists = True Then
            Else
                dirconsultee1.Create()
            End If
            '---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            NoOfDocs = 1
            For iCount = 0 To NoOfDocs - 1
                ServerPath = ""
                ServerPath = Server.MapPath("../uploaddocs/" & dirname & "/" & dirconsultee & "")
                ServerPath1 = dirname & "/" & dirconsultee
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(ServerPath)
                sConId = "m_txt_" & iCount & "_" & "UF" & iCount
                'sConId1 = doctitle(iCount)
                'sConId2 = docdescription(iCount)
                'sConId1 = doctitle
                'sConId2 = docdescription
                Dim ms As New MemoryStream(docs)
                'Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream(dirname & "/" & dirconsultee & "/" & sConId, IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)
                'ms.WriteTo(fs)

                'ms.Close()
                'fs.Close()
                'fs.Dispose()
                'Upload1 = fs
                'txtTitle = CType(tbluploaddoc.FindControl(sConId1), eCMSLib.Component.TextBox)
                'txtDesc = CType(tbluploaddoc.FindControl(sConId2), eCMSLib.Component.TextBox)
                Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
                'If sConId1 <> "" Then
                '    strDocTitle = sConId1
                'Else
                '    strDocTitle = ""
                'End If
                'If sConId2 <> "" Then
                '    strDocDesc = sConId2
                'Else
                '    strDocDesc = ""
                'End If

                If docs IsNot Nothing Then
                    'If FileFieldSelected(Upload1) = True Then

                    strFilename = sConId

                    If strFilename <> String.Empty Then
                        strOnlyFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFilename)

                        If Not eCMSLib.Common.Operation.CommonFunctions.isValidUserDefineFile(strOnlyFilename, ".doc,.docx,.pdf,.ppt,.pptx,.pps,.gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.bmp,.htm,.html") Then
                            'lblErroMsg.Visible = True
                            Dim strErroMsg As String = "Invalid File format. You can upload only files with.doc,.docx,.pdf,.ppt,.pptx,.pps,.gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.bmp,.htm,.html extesion."
                            'Return lblErroMsg.Text
                            'Return False
                            Context.Response.Write("{""Uploaddocs"":" & New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(strErroMsg) & "}")
                        End If

                        ServerPath = ServerPath & "/" & strOnlyFilename
                        ServerPath1 = dirname & "/" & dirconsultee & "/" & strOnlyFilename

                        'If Upload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 15000000 Then
                        '    'lblErroMsg.Visible = True
                        '    Dim strErroMsg As String = "File size is too large. Please try again."
                        '    Context.Response.Write("{""Uploaddocs"":" & New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(strErroMsg) & "}")
                        '    'Return lblErroMsg.Text
                        '    'Exit Function
                        'End If
                        Dim bln As Boolean
                        bln = objDoc.IsFileExist(ServerPath1, UserId)

                        If bln = True Then
                            'lblErroMsg.Visible = True
                            Dim strErroMsg As String = "This file " & strOnlyFilename & "has already been uploaded."
                            Context.Response.Write("{""Uploaddocs"":" & New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(strErroMsg) & "}")
                            ' Return lblErroMsg.Text
                            'Exit Function
                        End If

                        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        Dim BLNUpload As Boolean = ValidationForUpload(UserId, IdeaId)
                        If BLNUpload = False Then
                            Dim UploadedFile As Integer
                            Dim objDocs1 As New DocumentAndResponse
                            UploadedFile = objDocs1.CountUplodedFileForIdeaUser(UserId, IdeaId)
                            'Dim strErroMsg As String = "Your documents " & UploadedFile & "  have been uploaded ."
                            'Return lblErroMsg.Text
                            'Exit Function
                        End If
                        '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                        'eCMSLib.Common.Operation.CommonFunctions.UploadFile(Upload1, ServerPath, 15000000)
                        fs = New System.IO.FileStream(dirname & "/" & dirconsultee & "/" & sConId, IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)
                        ms.WriteTo(fs)

                        ms.Close()
                        fs.Close()
                        fs.Dispose()
                    End If



                    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    'Insert Data in  database for upload documents  track.
                    Dim sPath As String
                    Dim DocRefNumber As String
                    Dim UploadFileContForUser As Integer
                    Dim objDocs2 As New DocumentAndResponse
                    UploadFileContForUser = objDocs2.CountUplodedFileForIdeaUser(UserId, IdeaId)

                    If iCount = 0 Then
                        DocRefNumber = IdeaId & "-" & UserId & "-" & Date.Now.Day & "-" & Date.Now.Month & "-" & Date.Now.Year & "-" & UploadFileContForUser + iCount + 1
                    Else
                        DocRefNumber = IdeaId & "-" & UserId & "-" & Date.Now.Day & "-" & Date.Now.Month & "-" & Date.Now.Year & "-" & UploadFileContForUser + 1
                    End If

                    sPath = dirname & "/" & dirconsultee & "/" & strOnlyFilename

                    Dim oInfo As Hashtable = New Hashtable
                    oInfo.Add("n_fkIdeaId", IdeaId)
                    oInfo.Add("t_DocPath", sPath)
                    oInfo.Add("n_UplodedTime", "getdate()")
                    oInfo.Add("n_fkUserID", UserId)
                    oInfo.Add("t_UserType", "Consultee")
                    oInfo.Add("t_DocType", System.IO.Path.GetExtension(strOnlyFilename))
                    oInfo.Add("t_DocSize", fs.Length)
                    oInfo.Add("t_DocRefNumber", DocRefNumber)
                    oInfo.Add("t_DocTitle", strDocTitle)
                    oInfo.Add("t_DocDesc", strDocDesc)
                    objDoc.AddIdeaDocument(oInfo)

                    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    'End If
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            ''Throw ex
            objIdea.DeleteIdea(IdeaId, PartnerId) 'Added by Pinki to resolve the issue when file is invalid - (28 apr 2011)  
        End Try
        Return String.Empty
    End Function
    Public Function GetNumberOfUploadDocs(ByVal PartnerID As Integer) As Integer
        Dim str As String
        Dim Number As Integer
        str = "SELECT ISNULL(paravaluedtl,'0') paravaluedtl from tblparameterdtl  where fkparameterid='NoOFUpload_SubmittingIdea' and fkConsultPartnerID= " & PartnerID & "  "
        Number = eCMSLib.Common.Operation.DatabaseIntraction.GetSingleRowColumnValue(str)
        Return Number
    End Function
    Public Function GetAllowUploadIdeaDocs(ByVal PartnerID As Integer) As String
        Dim str As String
        Dim strAllow As String
        str = "SELECT paravaluedtl from tblparameterdtl  where fkparameterid='EnableUpload_SubmittingIdea' and fkConsultPartnerID= " & PartnerID & "  "
        strAllow = eCMSLib.Common.Operation.DatabaseIntraction.GetSingleRowColumnValue(str)
        Return strAllow
    End Function
    Public Function FileFieldSelected(ByVal FileField As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputFile) As Boolean
        ' Returns a True if the passed
        ' FileField has had a user post a file
        If FileField.PostedFile Is Nothing Then Return False
        If FileField.PostedFile.ContentLength = 0 Then Return False
        Return True
    End Function
    Public Function ValidationForUpload(ByVal UserID As Integer, ByVal IdeaID As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim objUserDoc As New DocumentAndResponse
        Dim bln As Boolean
        bln = objUserDoc.GetFileUploadCountForIdeaUser(UserID, IdeaID, Session("ConsultPartner"))
        Return bln
    End Function
```

**Upload Android method**

```
    /** android File upload start */
    public static String doFileUpload(String path, String URL) {

        final DataOutputStream dos;

        String exiting_file_path = path;

        Log.d("d file path--->", "" + path);

        String boundary = "*****";
        String twohypens = "--";
        String lineend = "\r\n";
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        int buferSize;
        int bytesRead;          
        String url_string = URL;

        try {
            Log.d("Debug", "Start Uploading");
            FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(
                    exiting_file_path);
            URL url = new URL(url_string);
            httpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpUrlConn.setDoInput(true);
            httpUrlConn.setDoOutput(true);
            httpUrlConn.setUseCaches(false);
            httpUrlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("connection", "Keep-Alive");
            httpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("content-type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            httpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("UserId", "" + SoapParsar.UserID);
            httpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("PartnerId", ""
                    + SoapParsar.PartnerID);
            httpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("IdeaId", "" + 1400);
            httpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("Path", "file://" + path);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(httpUrlConn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twohypens + boundary + lineend);
            dos.writeBytes("content-disposition:form-data; name=\"upload_file\"; filename=\""
                    + exiting_file_path + "\"" + lineend);
            dos.writeBytes(lineend);

            int buferAvailable = fileInStream.available();
            buferSize = Math.min(buferAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[buferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInStream.read(buffer, 0, buferSize);
            // -------------------
            if (isFromCamera) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Log.d("bit map hight", "--->" + resizedBitmap.getHeight());
                Log.d("bit map width", "--->" + resizedBitmap.getWidth());
                resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                dos.write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            } else {
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, buferSize);
                    buferAvailable = fileInStream.available();
                    buferSize = Math.min(buferAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInStream.read(buffer, 0, buferSize);
                }
            }
            // ---------------

            dos.writeBytes(lineend);
            dos.writeBytes(twohypens + boundary + twohypens + lineend);
            fileInStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream(
                    httpUrlConn.getInputStream());
            STR1 = inStream.readLine();
            while ((STRRRR = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("Debug", "Server Response " + STRRRR);
            }
            inStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /** in STRRRR you get name of photo */

        Log.d("File Uploded--->", "" + STR1);

        return STR1;
    }
```

Button Upload click code

```
   btnPost.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String title = ni_title.getText().toString();
                String detail = ni_detail.getText().toString();
                String tag = ni_tag.getText().toString();
                String directorate = ni_directorate.getText().toString();
                String filepath = ni_filepath.getText().toString();

                Log.d("local file path", "" + path + "/" + filepath);

                boolean post_idea = true;

                if (title.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    ni_title.setError("Enter Title");
                    post_idea = false;
                }

                if (detail.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    ni_detail.setError("Enter Descrebtion");
                    post_idea = false;
                }

                if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    ni_tag.setError("Enter Tag");
                    post_idea = false;
                }

                if (directorate.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    ni_directorate.setError("Enter Directorate");
                    post_idea = false;
                }

                // if(filepath.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                // ni_filepath.setError("select file");
                // }
                if (!Select_c) {
                    Toast.makeText(add_new_idea.this, "Select Category",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    post_idea = false;
                }

                if (post_idea) {

                    try {
                        General_class.arrayPost.clear();

                        General_class.arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "IdeaId", "0"));
                        General_class.arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "ideaTitle", "" + title));
                        General_class.arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "ideadescription", "" + detail));
                        General_class.arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "SessionId", "0"));
                        General_class.arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "UserID", "" + SoapParsar.UserID));
                        General_class.arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "UserType", "" + SoapParsar.Usertype));
                        General_class.arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "emailid", "dhaval@elegantmicroweb.com"));
                        General_class.arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "PartnerID", "" + SoapParsar.PartnerID));
                        General_class.arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "tags", "" + tag));
                        General_class.arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                "categoryids", "" + selected));
                        /*
                         * General_class.arrayPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                         * "categoryids", "" + selected));
                         */
                        // ni_filepath

                        String para = "?IdeaId=0&ideaTitle=" + title
                                + "&ideadescription=" + detail
                                + "&SessionId=0&UserID=" + SoapParsar.UserID
                                + "&emailid=&UserType=" + SoapParsar.Usertype
                                + "&PartnerID=" + SoapParsar.PartnerID
                                + "&tags=" + tag + "&categoryids=" + selected;

                        // String Res = General_class
                        // .Call_Http_URL_PostMethod(SoapParsar.BASEURL_LOGIN
                        // + "/AddEditIdea");

                        String URL = SoapParsar.BASEURL_LOGIN + "/AddEditIdea"
                                + para;
                        URL = General_class.replaceSpace(URL);
                        Log.e("URL--->", "" + URL);
                        String Res = General_class.GETMethod(URL);
                        Log.e("post idea-->", "" + Res);

                        /*
                         * General_class.doFileUpload(ni_filepath.getText()
                         * .toString(), SoapParsar.BASEURL_LOGIN +
                         * "/UploadFiles");
                         */
                    /*  
                        General_class.doFileUpload("" + path + "/" +ni_filepath.getText().toString(),
                                  SoapParsar.BASEURL_LOGIN + "/UploadFiles");
                        */

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                      General_class.doFileUpload(path + "/" +
                      ni_filepath.getText().toString(),
                      SoapParsar.BASEURL_LOGIN + "/UploadFiles?UserId=" +
                      SoapParsar.UserID + "&PartnerId=" + SoapParsar.PartnerID
                      + "&IdeaId=0&filename="
                      +ni_filepath.getText().toString());   

                    Log.e("path---->111-->", "" + path);

                    /* General_class.doFileUpload("" + path + "/" +ni_filepath.getText().toString(),
                      SoapParsar.BASEURL_LOGIN + "/UploadFiles");*/

                    // General_class.doFileUpload(path + "/"+
                    // ni_filepath.getText().toString(),SoapParsar.BASEURL_LOGIN
                    // + "?op=UploadFiles");

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(add_new_idea.this, "enter all details",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Error Log:

```
URL--->(21331): http://10.0.0.230:81/samplewebservice/webservice.asmx/AddEditIdea?IdeaId=0&ideaTitle=kihgtff&ideadescription=bhhhjhhb&SessionId=0&UserID=430&emailid=&UserType=Consultee&PartnerID=9&tags=%20&categoryids=17


04-01 18:07:38.476: D/d file path--->(21331): /mnt/sdcard/Aaa.JPG
04-01 18:07:38.476: D/Debug(21331): Start Uploading
04-01 18:07:38.726: W/System.err(21331): java.io.FileNotFoundException: `http://10.0.0.230:81/samplewebservice/webservice.asmx/UploadFiles?UserId=430&PartnerId=9&IdeaId=0&filename=Aaa.JPG`
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at com.idea_mobile.General_class.doFileUpload(General_class.java:640)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at com.idea_mobile.add_new_idea$2.onClick(add_new_idea.java:238)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-01 18:07:38.750: W/System.err(21331):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 18:07:38.750: D/File Uploded--->(21331): null
04-01 18:07:38.750: E/path---->111-->(21331): /mnt/sdcard
```

Its give me File not fount at this line:

```
DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream(
                    httpUrlConn.getInputStream());
```

Comment: I have faced the similar issue and what helped me was:
I was not sending all parameters required to the web service or they are not as per the web service declaration

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the client side to read the file, that seems to be what you are trying to do.

Personally I would have my upload method signature something along the lines of:

```
//Server
public void UploadFile(bytes[] file, string name)
{
  //Store the BLOB object
}
//Client
public void SendFile()
{
  var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("Filename");
  UploadFile(bytes, new FileInfo("Filename").Name);
}
```

Please note that you have tagged your question purely in `C#` so that is what answer I have given, if you need to convert it please use an [online convertor](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).